# I can't call JpaReposistory api in a Vaadin Component

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I am while new to Vaadin and Spring Boot and I am trying to make a small app that can do all CRUD methods. I am making this Form that will take in all the data from fields, save it to a model object and save that to my database but it won't let me.

**StudentRepo**

```
package com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.entity.Student;
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{
}
```

**StudentForm**

```
package com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.vaadin;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.data.ValidationException;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.entity.Student;
import com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.repo.StudentRepo;

@SpringComponent
public class StudentForm extends FormLayout{
    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;
    Student student = new Student();

    private TextField firstName = new TextField("First Name");
    private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last Name");
    private TextField email = new TextField("Email");
    private Button save = new Button("Save");
    private Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    private Binder<Student> binder = new Binder<>(Student.class);



    public StudentForm() {
        HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout(save, delete);
        addComponents(firstName, lastName, email, buttons);

        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        binder.setBean(student);
        setSizeUndefined();

        save.addClickListener(event -> {
            try {
                binder.writeBean(student);
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                saveStudent(student);
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveStudent(Student theStudent) {
        repo.save(theStudent);
    }

}
```

**MainContent where StudentForm get call**

```
package com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.vaadin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.assertj.core.util.Lists;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.icons.VaadinIcons;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.CssLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;
import com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.entity.Student;
import com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.repo.StudentRepo;

import javassist.expr.NewArray;

@SpringComponent
public class MainContent extends VerticalLayout {
    @Autowired
    private Student student;
    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;

    private StudentForm studentForm = new StudentForm();



    private CssLayout filterLayout;
    private TextField filterText;
    private Button filterBtn;
    private HomeUI homeUI;
    private Grid<Student> studentGrid;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        setStudents(repo.findAll());
    }

    private void setStudents(List<Student> findAll) {
        studentGrid.setItems(findAll);
    }

    public MainContent() {
        addFilter();
        addMainContent();
    }

    private void addMainContent() {
        HorizontalLayout main = new HorizontalLayout();
        studentGrid = new Grid<>(Student.class);
        studentGrid.setColumns("firstName", "lastName", "email");
        main.addComponentsAndExpand(studentGrid);
        main.addComponents(studentForm);
        studentGrid.setSizeFull();
        addComponents(main);
    }

    private void addFilter() {
        filterLayout = new CssLayout();
        filterLayout.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);

        filterText = new TextField();
        filterText.setPlaceholder("filter by name...");

        filterBtn = new Button(VaadinIcons.CLOSE);

        filterLayout.addComponents(filterText, filterBtn);

        HorizontalLayout toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(filterLayout);
        addComponent(toolbar);
    }
}
```

In Summary, I have the MainContent component which display a grid to the left then display StudentForm on the right.

All is fine until I try to repo.save(theStudent) inside the StudentForm,and I got this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vinh.vaadin.allinone.vaadin.StudentForm.lambda$0(StudentForm.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor309.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor308.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116) ~[vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.4.1.jar:8.4.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

However, if I put `repo.save()` inside a `saveStudent()` method in the `MainContent`, pass that `MainContent` to the `StudentForm` then call `saveStudent()` method from there then it will work. why?

Another question I have is in the MainContent, I have to add `repo.findAll()` in the `@PostConstruct` for it to work, if I put it any where else that is not @PostConstruct, then it won't work, why is this?

Comment: added @Repository, still won't work. and by the time it gets to the try-catch-finally blog, I tried sysout, student is not null.

Comment: please post full exception

Comment: @JohnJoe edited

Answer (score 1):

Your StudentRepo class should be annotated with @Component since you are creating its bean in the StudentForm class.

When the bean of the StudentForm is created it requires the bean of the StudentRepo class which is not created because you have not marked it as @Component. So when you try to access the methods of the StudentRepo a null pointer exception is thrown

```
@Component
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

You can also use @Repository annotation to specify this is a dao layer class.
@Repository extends from @Component and is used only to keep the naming consistent.
So both the annotations will work

Answer (score 0):

You are calling bindInstanceFields, but you have not annotated your Fields with @PropertyId(..) annotations. Hence it probably does nothing, and your edits are never bound to your Student bean. See JavaDoc

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.4/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html#bindInstanceFields-java.lang.Object-

Comment: The bindInstanceFields on default bind all fields to Entity’s properties base on the naming Convention, my Entity has a property call lastName, one of the textField is called lastName, those 2 will be bound together. @PropertyId let you bind a field and a property that have different name.